# How do I pass an array of textures to a fragment shader before MacOS 10.13?

Tags: arrays, swift, shader, textures, metal

In Metal, `array<T, Count>` was provided in 10.13, High Sierra, but that's too new. I'd like to be as backward compatible as I can.

However, Metal gives errors if I try to declare the argument as an array or as a pointer:

```
constant texture2d<half> *Texture [[texture(0)]]
```

The only option I see is to use `texture2d_array<half>`, but those are annoying to deal with from the Swift side. Suggestions?

Comment: You could add some more tags for more visibility. The `metal` tag has relatively few questions and tag watchers so not many people will see your question. I could add some for you but I don't know which ones are appropriate. A programming language tag would be best in giving question visibility.

Comment: @Shaido Will do and thanks for the edit and the comment :)